# how to navigate data between two screens in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have homeScreen, which every another screen returns to it.
and one of the screens have parameters from TextField, which I need in the homeScreen, how I can navigate these parameters to the home?
NOTE: when I use constructor, the other screens show an error in the line that navigate to Home because there is no parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use an optional parameter in your constructor:

```dart
Homepage({String textfield});
```

and use it on your Homepage (don't forget that this value is nullable)

Or you need to use some kind of state management with `ValueNotifiers`

Comment: I tried that, but when use  ` HomeScreen(nameController.value.text, detailsController.value.text)` it give me **Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 2 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.**

Comment: You probably forgot to declare the arguments in the definition of your widget:
https://gist.github.com/BLKKKBVSIK/89de7eda8387f72d0c6291aff704993b

Comment: It is giving me a hint that "add required keyword" , sorry for that but I am still new and don't understand too much

Comment: Also I have more than one parameter, should I declare them as opptional like this? " HomePage({this.name, this.details})

Comment: Yes you can, add them as such, can you provide a working CodePen minimal exemple of your code ? So I can see the exact error and when it occurs ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! but I changed it :( I removed the Screen I want data from and I used the **showModalBottomSheet**, so I got the data from it. Thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232147/discussion-between-blkkkbvsik-and-abrar-lasebai).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data using parameters

```
    class XYZ extends StatelessWidget {
      final TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();
    
      void navigationFunction() {
//send the data from XYZ to HomePage
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HomePage(textValue: textController.text)),
        );
      }
    }
        
    class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      const HomePage({this.textValue});
      final String textValue; //use this textValue in HomePage
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold();
      }
    }
```